# Automate Exporting Quickbooks Desktop csv file

Tags: csv, quickbooks

I need to connect Quickbooks Desktop with a webapp. After trying to use the webconnector and realizing that it has deprecated mysql instead of mysqli commands, I decided to just use csv exports and import those to my webapp. How would I then automate creating those csv files? I looked into AutoHotKey, is there an easier way of doing this?
Thank you!

Comment: You know you can just change `mysql` to `mysqli` in your $dsn string, and it will then use the NOT DEPRECATED `mysqli_*` functions instead, right? Literally a 1-character fix to your problem...

Comment: I tried that, you have to change more than just that, some parameters are backwards and some others when changing to mysqli expect a different type of parameter which would require a full refactor of the MYSQL connector.

Comment: Then you're using old or the wrong code. I literally use this code with thousands of businesses every single day, using only MySQLi on PHP7. It works fine. Genuinely trying to help here -- you're doing something wrong or you just haven't looked at the example enough or something. It works fine. I would recommend you post your code/post what you're stuck on as a separate question.